# How to line up the text on 2 side by side divs horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 main divs, one is on the left and one on the right. The div on the left is a Wordpress plugin contact form 7. It has a list of questions.

To do this, I want to now individually address each question on my second div. I created smaller divs within the second div.

How do I align these smaller divs inside my second div so, that they line up horizontally? How do I it so, that it lines up in all screens and browsers?

The usual stuff like margin-top, padding-top in X px doesn't work.

Here is a screenshot: https://postimg.org/image/kedd5rbun/

Comment: Just use consistent styling between the 2 elements. "The usual stuff like margin-top, padding-top in X px doesnt work" - if you match font sizes, line heights, margins/paddings, they will match up. Also, please share some code.

Comment: Maybe tables or JS code, anyone works for you?

Comment: i have different content in the 2 elements so i cant rly just match font size/line heights/magin and padding in a linear fashion, after further looking at it...it seems whats causing the problem is that some browsers will have certain content at 5 lines while others will have it at 6

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex.

```css
.qrow{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}
.qu{
  flex-basis:50%;
  border:1px solid green;
}
.an{
  flex-basis:50%;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="qrow">
    <div class="qu">Question<br/>question</div>
    <div class="an">Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qrow">
    <div class="qu">Question</div>
    <div class="an">Answer<br/>Answer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```